# prevent duplicate entry for this case

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I want to prevent duplicate entry from userform, let me explain, for example I have a userform with two fields, the first one is NAME  and is a textbox the second one is departement and it is a comboboxlist and a button "add to base"
so I want to authorize for example in sheet

```
A      | B
marcel | IT
marcel | WAREHOUSE
```

(A is column of names, B column of departement)

but no authorize

```
A      | B 
marcel | IT 
marcel | IT
```

so how can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Dictionary object to collect unique values. The Dictionary object is a collection of Keys (which are unique) with corresponding values.

I'll  give you an example of using Dictionary keys to get unique values. In this one, I have created a Userform with a combobox with the code below as a sample:

My Range:
[Screenshot of Sample Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhPPG.png)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize
    Dim dict As Object 'Declare (Late binding)
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Create dictionary object (Late binding)

'Loop through your range where you want to collect unique values
    'loop through your desired range
    For Each cellFromColumnA In Sheet1.Range("A1:A7")
        'this will check first if value exists on dictionary. Value won't be added on the combobox if value already exists on the dictionary
        If Not dict.Exists(cellFromColumnA.Value) Then
            'add cell value as dictionary key as a reference
            dict.Add cellFromColumnA.Value, ""
            'add value to combobox1
            ComboBox1.AddItem cellFromColumnA.Value
        End If
    Next

    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

This will be the result: [Screenshot of The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxqVI.png)

You may use the code above and change based on your needs. You may refer to [this link](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) to learn more about Dictionary object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but how can adapt this context of dictionnary to my problem ?

Comment: I have provided an example on how you can use dictionary to get unique values. I won't be able to help you exactly with your problem since you haven't posted your code on your question.